# Why does the newer 'setState' method not recognize my event.target?

Tags: reactjs

Is the newer setState syntax not recommended for use with events?
While debugging, I saw that the first letter I typed came through with
a proper e.target.value.
Immediately afterwards though, I got the TypeError you see below.

```
// onChange(e) {
//     this.setState(prevState => {
//        return { username: e.target.value} <--- TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
//     })
// }
```

// obviously the setState below works fine

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ username: e.target.value});
}

<input  type="text"
        placeholder="What is your username?"
        onChange={this.onChange}
        // onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} - also tried this
        value={this.state.username}/>
```

Comment: Because you forgot proper modern syntax: `onChange={ e => this.onChange(e) }` which you need to use to make sure that "this" keeps pointing to whatever "this" points to during `render()` (i.e., your component, rather than the the event handling global scope, once it finally gets resolved by the browser's native event manager)

Comment: doing that was one of my attempts - same problem results

Comment: As someone who uses React for their work: no. If you use arrow functions, then your change handler _will_ get called correctly, so if using proper syntax doesn't solve your problem, you need to show a [mcve] because what you describe as the problem, is _not_ the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I missed the error in the first place which is `e.target` is being null here. So, the real problem is not extracting the value from the event or using `event.persist()` there as @trixn explained in his/her answer. But, my answer includes this step though. So, it worked :)

---

Neither of them works if you don't bind your `onChange` function for `this`. Here is the working version of your code that you say does not work:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { username: "" };
   onChange = (e) => {
     const { value } = e.target;
     this.setState(prevState => {
       return { username: value}
   })
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text"
          placeholder="What is your username?"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.username} />
        <p>Username: {this.state.username}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I just used an arrow function instead of implicitly binding it. So it is bond automatically. Also, I extracted the `value` from `e.target` for React's synthetic events handling. We can't use events properly if we use them in a callback function like in `setState`'s here. This is why I extracted it then use as a separate variable.

Comment: Any comment for the downvote? This code works without any problem. I just wonder what is the actual problem here?

Comment: Destructuring e.target seems to have done the trick. I never knew it sometimes becomes a necessity. Always just assumed it was a nice way to neaten up your code. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I've updated my answer and explained why we need extraction here. Also, if this answer helped you please consider accepting it.

Comment: The problem is probably not that the handler was not bound as that would have led to another error. The problem is, that you can't just use react events in an async fashion without persisting them before.

Comment: Yes, @trixn, it was the problem and I've updated my answer a minute ago. We should have understood that from the error `e.target` is being null there.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the event in an asynchronous way by accessing it in the callback function you passed to `setState()`. By the time react calls your updater function all properties on the event have already been cleared.

[From the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling):

> The `SyntheticEvent` is pooled. This means that the `SyntheticEvent`
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
>   such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

To avoid that you either need to persist the event by calling `event.perist()`. This will enable you to use it later.

Or you assign the `value` you are interested in to a local variable that can be used asynchronously:

```
onChange(e) {
    const username = e.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => ({username}));
}
```

Actually in your specific example you do not need the callback based version of `setState()` at all as you aren't updating the state based on previous state or props.

Comment: Thanks! So the simpler setState method is fine to use then, it seems. Just thought I should avoid it.

Comment: @dwilbank It's fine to use the simple version as long as the updated value is not calculated from state or props in any way.

Comment: Also upvoted this answer. You can use the regular `setState` as you don't need here. But what if React deprecates it in the future? I am thinking this possibility and straddle if I use the new one or not.

Comment: @devserkan I don't think this will be deprecated any time as in a lot of cases it is the preferred way to use `setState()`.

Comment: Hopefully not since like you said people still use it if there is no need for the previous state.